# Is there a way to make IE save a computed webpage

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, save

I've got a project that needs to be able to save; but cannot include server side code to do so.

I've structured the code to make sure that it has no external libraries or CSS files, and can simple press CTRL+S on all browsers, **EXCEPT IE**, and have the page look just the way it should.

In IE however it just looks like the default page, without any of the changes.

**TL;DR**: Can you save the computed page in IE (8+ preferably but 9+ is fine too.)

Comment: Have you looked into IE's implementation of `document.execCommand("SaveAs");`?

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to my attention, it certainly does give me the computed values!

Comment: No problem, I remember taking advantage of that in the past for a javascript templater :)